# What is a shared device id between browser and app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I'm working on some POC, in this, I need to open a webpage, the web will send an **id** to my server to store, then open an app (both Android and iOS); in the app, I will use the **id** to look up if the webpage has been opened prior to opening the app.

The problem is I don't know what **id** I can use to uniquely identify a device. This id needs to be persisted as well, so if I open the webpage today and then open it again next week, the 2 **ids** need to be the same. I'm a mobile developer, so I don't know what can be obtained with javascript and whether that is shared with the app as well.

Thanks

Comment: On iOS (and probably on Android now) there explicitly isn't such an identifier for privacy reasons.  You should have your server generate the id and then include it in the url it uses to open the app.  The app can then store the value for use in the future.

Comment: yea, but the problem is that I need it to be the same on the device every time. so if users uninstall the app, the generated id has to be the same. Maybe a way to retrieve hardware id as that is will remain the same

Comment: No, this is not possible. You cannot access hardware identifiers for privacy reasons. On iOS you can store an identifier in the keychain that will be kept across app reinstallation

Comment: Thank you, looks like I'll have to look in other directions to support tall platforms

Comment: Trying to uniquely identify a device rather than a user has other potential issues; Users can reset their device or buy a new device.  If you break the screen and take it to Apple for either AppleCare replacement or chargeable replacement they typically just swap your phone.  In general you should not tie a user to a device.

Comment: Yea, I understand, but my POC only cares about the device. Its purpose is to prevent fraudulent  activity of repeating some operation on the same device.